Can't resolve type issues on memoized React Higher-Order Components
In my React TS project I'm working on a component (RecipeNamer) that lets the user type into an input. The input is then sent to a React Context whose provider is the parent (RecipeCreator), which renders three children components. All of them update a different slice of the Context, and I want them not to render when their part of Context is not changed.
To achieve this, I decided to create three Higher Order Components that wrap each child in a React.memo() function, extract the correspondent slice of Context, and render the children passing them the part of Context extracted as props:
hocs.tsx
export function withDetails<T extends object>(Component: ComponentType<T & { ingredients: Array<string> }>) {
    const MemoizedComponent = memo(Component);

    return (props: Omit<T, "title" | "difficulty" | "minutesNeeded">) => {
        const { title, difficulty, minutesNeeded } = useContext(RecipeCreatedContext);
        
        return <MemoizedComponent {...(props as T)} title={title} difficulty={difficulty} minutesNeeded={minutesNeeded} />;
    };
};

RecipeNamer.tsx
interface RecipeNamerProps {
    title: string;
    difficulty: Difficulty;
    minutesNeeded: number;
    dispatcher: React.Dispatch<RecipeCreatedAction>;
}

const difficultyValues = ["Easy", "Medium", "Hard"];

const RecipeNamer = (props: RecipeNamerProps) => {
    const { title, difficulty, minutesNeeded } = props;

    const userData: UserData | null = useAppSelector(getUserData);

    const experienceLevel = useRef<Experience>({level: "Unexperienced"});

    useEffect(() => {
        if (userData) {
            experienceLevel.current = calculateChefExperience(userData)
        }
    }, [userData]);


    const handleRecipeNameChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        // @TODO: call the dispatcher function passed as props.
    }


    return (
        <Box>
            <TextField id="recipe-title" label="Recipe title" variant="outlined" 
                       value={title} onChange={(event) => handleRecipeNameChange(event as React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)}/>
            <TextField id="minutes-needed" label="Minutes needed" variant="outlined"
                        value={minutesNeeded} /> 
            <TextField id="recipe-difficulty" label="Difficulty" variant="outlined"
                        defaultValue={difficulty} select>
                {difficultyValues.map((option) => <option key={option} value={option}>{option}</option>)}
            </TextField> 
            <Typography>Chef: {userData?.displayName}, {experienceLevel.current.level}</Typography>
        </Box>
    )
}

export const RecipeNamerMemoized = withDetails(RecipeNamer);

RecipeCreator.tsx
function recipeCreatedReducer(state: RecipeCreatedState, action: RecipeCreatedAction): RecipeCreatedState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'edit-ingredients':
            return {...state, ingredients: action.payload as string[]};
        case 'edit-preparation':
            return {...state, preparation: action.payload as string};
        case 'edit-image':
            return {...state, image: action.payload as File}
        default:
            throw Error('Unknown action for recipeCreatedReducer.');
    }
}

const initialState: RecipeCreatedState = {
    title: "",
    ingredients: [],
    preparation: "",
    minutesNeeded: 0,
    difficulty: "Easy",
    image: null,
    imageURL: ''
};

export const RecipeCreatedContext = createContext<RecipeCreatedState>(initialState);


export const RecipeCreator = () => {

    const [recipeCreated, recipeCreatedDispatch] = useReducer(recipeCreatedReducer, initialState);

    const [toaster, setToaster] = useState<ToasterData>({
        open: false,
        message: "",
        type: "success",
        transition: "Slide",
        key: null
    });

    const loggedUser = useAppSelector(getLoggedUser);

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!loggedUser) {
            alert("You must sign in before.");
            navigate('/sign-in');
        }
    }, [loggedUser, navigate]);

    const handleCloseToaster = () => {
        setToaster((prevState) => { return { ...prevState, open: false} });
    }

    const handleSubmitRecipe = async () => {
        if (!recipeCreated || !recipeCreated.title || !recipeCreated.ingredients || !recipeCreated.preparation || !recipeCreated.minutesNeeded || !recipeCreated.difficulty) {
            setToaster({
                open: true,
                message: "Can't submit a recipe with missing arguments. Please provide all the fields needed.",
                type: "error",
                transition: "Slide",
                key: "Error"
            })
        }
        else {
            try {
                if (recipeCreated.image) {
                    const recipeCreatedWithDetails: Omit<RecipeDetails, "id" | "imageURL"> = {
                        ...recipeCreated,
                        chef: loggedUser ? loggedUser.uid : "",
                        views: 0,
                        likes: 0
                    }
                    const retValue = await publishNewRecipe(recipeCreatedWithDetails, recipeCreated.image);
                    if (retValue) setToaster({
                        open: true,
                        message: `New recipe "${recipeCreated?.title}" published successfully!`,
                        type: "success",
                        transition: "Slide",
                        key: recipeCreated.title 
                    })
                }
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error("Error while publishing a new recipe in the database: ", error);
                setToaster({
                    open: true,
                    message: (error as Error).message,
                    type: "error",
                    transition: "Slide",
                    key: "Error"
                });
            }
        }
    }
        
    
    return (
        <>
            <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" minHeight="100vh">
                <RecipeAppBar />
                <RecipeCreatedContext.Provider value={recipeCreated}>
                    <Box display="flex" flexDirection="row" width="100%" justifyContent="space-evenly">
                        <Box flexDirection="column" height="100%" width="50%">
                            <IngredientsSelectorMemoized setToaster={setToaster} dispatcher={recipeCreatedDispatch}/>
                            <RecipeNamerMemoized dispatcher={recipeCreatedDispatch} />
                        </Box>
                        <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" height="100%" alignItems="center">
                            <RecipeImageMemoized dispatcher={recipeCreatedDispatch} currentImageURL={recipeCreated.imageURL}/>
                            <RecipeEditorMemoized dispatcher={recipeCreatedDispatch} />
                            <Button onClick={handleSubmitRecipe}>Submit</Button>
                        </Box>
                        <Snackbar 
                            anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" }}
                            autoHideDuration={4000}
                            open={toaster.open}
                            key={toaster.key}
                            onClose={() => handleCloseToaster()}
                            sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between", alignItems: "center"}}
                        >
                            <Alert severity={toaster.type} variant="filled" sx={{display:"flex", flexDirection:"row", alignItems: "center"}}>
                                <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center">
                                    <Typography>{toaster.message}</Typography>
                                    <Close onClick={() => handleCloseToaster()} sx={{ marginLeft: "2%", cursor: "pointer" }}/>
                                </Box>
                            </Alert>
                        </Snackbar>
                    </Box>
                </RecipeCreatedContext.Provider>
            </Box>       
        </>
    )
}

Even though to me it seems correct, I'm getting the same Typescript error for all the three HOCs I've written (I've only provided the withDetails() one here, but they're all similar), and the error is highlighted in the return <MemoizedComponent {...(props as T)} title={title} difficulty={difficulty} minutesNeeded={minutesNeeded} />.
Typescript says:
Type 'T & { title: string; difficulty: Difficulty; minutesNeeded: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ((PropsWithoutRef<T & { ingredients: string[]; }> & RefAttributes<Component<T & { ingredients: string[]; }, any, any>>) | PropsWithRef<...>)'.
  Type 'T & { title: string; difficulty: Difficulty; minutesNeeded: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PropsWithRef<T & { ingredients: string[]; }>'.
    Type 'T & { title: string; difficulty: Difficulty; minutesNeeded: number; }' is not assignable to type 'PropsWithRef<T & { ingredients: string[]; }>'.ts(2322)
const MemoizedComponent: React.MemoExoticComponent<ComponentType<T & {
    ingredients: Array<string>;
}>>

Can anyone help me with this one, please? I've tried multiple ways of re-writing the props specifying correspondent separate interfaces, but to no avail. The error stays more or less the same.
